# Mapping versioning for config and infra corresponding to application code version

Tags: git, terraform, configuration, version-control, devops

I have an application that has something like below structure
Service A  - application and  environment configuration, infrastructure dependencies (Queue, DB etc) etc.
Service B -  application and  environment configuration

Following the advise in [response here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/12803/best-practices-for-app-and-infrastructure-code-repositories) my application can be structured in either (answer 1)
Git(SCM).

```
-Service A
    src
    config
    infra
--Service B 
    src
    config
    infra

or
```

Answer 2 :

```
--Service A
    src
--Service B
    src
-Config (here there are configuration common to services/crosscutting + service specific)
     common.yml
     --service A
       application.test.yml
       :
     --service B
       application.dev.yml
-Infra
     env
```

From multiples posts the general consensus seems to be to have separate code and config from the main repo. By config what I mean is say .env file for now which is different for different env.

If so then how is versioning of the 3 maintained. ie Example

```
Version 2.0.0 
App code    - src depends on AWS SQS queue
Config code - .env for App code 2.0.0 that has SQS specific params also 
Infra code  - Cloud formation (general + SQS)

Version 3.0.0 
App code  - src depends on Kafka 
Config code - .env for App code 3.0.0 that has Kafka specific params 
Infra code - cf templates (general + Kafka )
```

How can we version it such that AppCode 3.0.0 goes with corresponding config and IAC. With monorepo concept our problem is different teams doing the infra and having their own processes.

*PS - I could not comment and ask on the original question since I did not have enough points hence a separate question.*

Answer (score 0):

My proposal for that case is:

Create a branch for each service from a master branch:

### Development team A

```
git checkout -b service-a master
```

#### commit your changes to service-a branch

```
git commit -m "all changes"
```

#### Create a tag Version 2.0.0

```
git tag -a v2.0.0 -m "Version 2.0.0 description"
```

#### Push the tag to the remote repository

```
git push origin v2.0.0
```

---

### Development team A

#### do the same thing for Service b

```
git checkout -b service-b master
```

#### commit your changes to service-b branch

```
git commit -m "all changes"
```

#### Create a tag Version 3.0.0

```
git tag -a v3.0.0 -m "Version 3.0.0 description"
```

#### Push the tag to the remote repository

```
git push origin v3.0.0
```

The main idea is to create a branch for each service. Additionally, you can create a common infrastructure folder and create policies in your version control repository to grant specific user permissions to avoid changes from the developer team that depends on that team's experience on Terraform.